# Return multiple ids when there are the same value in the database

Tags: java, android, sql

Will this return multiple ID´S if there are  multiple rows whit the same value(dataClicked) in COL_4 ?
COL_1="ID";

```
        public int getDateId(String dateClicked) {

        int dateID=0;
        String last_query = "SELECT " + COL_1  + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " = '" + dateClicked + "'";
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(last_query, null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
        {
            dateID = c.getInt(0);
        }
        c.close();
        return dateID;
    }
```

If it isn't can I store the values in an array ? And how can I do that

Comment: Will your method return multiple values?  No.  Can you store it in an array?  Yes.

Comment: Can you elaborate a method that returns multiple values and stores them in an array and then returns it ?

Comment: Step 1: Create an array.  Step 2: Populate it.  Step 3: Declare victory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `COL_4` with the same value as `dateClicked` then multiple `COL_1` will be returned. You can add them to list like this:

```
public List<Integer> getDateIds(String dateClicked) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    String last_query = "SELECT " + COL_1  + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " = '" + dateClicked + "'";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        ids.add(c.getInt(0));

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    return ids;
}
```

Comment: And how can I get that arrayList ? Like use it in a method, if it was a normal array I would ids[number] , how do I do it whit that ?